# Метод poll_wait()

Tags: linux

Объясните более подробно , пожалуйста, как работает данный метод. Я не понял описания на английском. Единственное, что я понял для чего нужен поллинг - получение информации, например, доступно ли чтение или запись. Но как работает poll_wait. Не понимаю кого и для чего он добавляет у очередь ожидания. Могли бы вы более подробно объяснить назначение данной функции.Заранее спасибо

Comment: в каком контексте ты с оной функцией встретился?

Comment: Модули ядра. Например когда мы открываем файл устройства в программе в адресном пространстве и вызываем select, poll. Что делается на уровне ядра? Конкретно в модуле

Comment: Тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234496/why-do-we-need-to-call-poll-wait-in-poll  — дан ответ. Но поскольку я совершенно не в теме разработки в ядре, то понял только, что этим вызовом драйвер себя добавляет в список сущностей, которые могут разбудить poll()'ящий процесс. Не могу судить, насколько это верно, так что комментарием, а не ответом. Вдруг поможет.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux_kernel_22/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

`poll_wait ()` добавляет текущий процесс к списку (*очереди ожидания*) тех, которые нужно пробудить при поступлении данных/доступности записи в устройство. Для этого драйвер должен вызвать `wake_up_interruptible()` для той же очереди при нужном событии, что пробудит все процессы, добавленные в очередь.

### Как работает `poll ()`

> Например когда мы открываем файл устройства в программе в адресном пространстве и вызываем select, poll. Что делается на уровне ядра?

Вызывается системный вызов. Пусть будет [`poll()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/fs/select.c#L1013) (c select всё аналогично). Он приводит данные к внутреннему формату ядра и вызывает [`do_poll()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/fs/select.c#L837), который начинает [цикл](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/fs/select.c#L856) ожидания. Сначала он [проходит](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/fs/select.c#L873) по всем файловым дескрипторам переданным `poll`'ом, вызывая [`do_pollfd()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/fs/select.c#L807).

`do_pollfd()` по сути просто обёртка над вызовом (через [`vfs_poll()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/include/linux/poll.h#L82) для последних ядер) специфического poll-метода для конкретного файла, указанный в `.poll` в его `struct file_operations`. Файл может быть как файлом устройства, сокетом, трубой или простым файлом (хотя последнее имеет не много смысла, разве что для `/proc/kmsg` или чего-то подобного).

Как пишут в [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) (см. [глава 6/poll and select](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-3.shtml)), `.poll()` обычно состоит из двух шагов:

1. Вызов poll_wait для одной или более *очередей ожидания* и добавления к ним процесса.
2. Возврат битовой маски, описывающей, какие **к данному моменту** операции (чтение/запись) могут быть произведены с дескриптором.

*Очереди ожидания* — это по сути простой двусвязный список процессов. Но все операции с ним проводятся как с непрозрачной структурой через [своё API](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/wait.h).  Обычно каждое устройство имеет свои независимые одну-две очереди (для чтения и записи).

На примере `/dev/random`, [`random_poll()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/wait.h) вызывает пресловутый `poll_wait()` для обеих своих очередей, а затем проверяет, есть ли готовые данные на чтение/запись, и выставляет соответствующие флаги.

Для вызовов poll/select `poll_wait()` раскрывается в [`__pollwait()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.3/source/fs/select.c#L221), который копируют адресс очереди в структуру связанную с текущем вызовом, а затем добавляет текущий процесс в эту очередь с помощью `init_waitqueue_func_entry()`/`add_wait_queue()`.

Как уже сказано, после завершения метод `.poll()` возвращается битовую маску доступных флагов, которую анализирует `do_pollfd()` и если он заметит событие запрошенное пользователем, то вернёт `do_poll()` ненулевое значение. После чего `do_poll()` продолжит обход оставшихся дескрипторов.

Если ни для одного дескриптора желанного события не произошло, то `do_poll()` [проверяет](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/select.c#L912) не вышел ли таймаут. А затем заводит будильник и [отправляется спать](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/select.c#L917).

Пробудить ото сна его может одно из трёх: или <s>прозвенел проклятущий будильник</s> кончился timeout, или процесс получил какой-либо сигнал, или из очереди ожидания. Последнее происходит по явному вызову из драйвера `wake_up_interruptible()` (который пробуждает все процессы добавленные в очередь), связанного с очередью, например для `/dev/random` [здесь](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/random.c#L726). После чего `do_poll ()` снова обходит все дескрипторы через `do_pollfd()`→`.poll()` (само собой, повторно не добавляя дескриптор в очередь).

Если `do_poll()` дождался нужного события/сигнала/таймаута, то он возвращает управление `poll`'у, который подготавливает данные для пользователя и вызывает [`poll_freewait()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/select.c#L138), которая помимо освобождения памяти под внутренние структуры `poll`'а [удаляет](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/select.c#L151) процесс из всех связанных очередей.